# How to use weatherstack.com api

Tags: python, python-3.x, weather-api, rasa

Hi I'm pretty new to python. I try to make a chatbot with rasa for personal use. Would like to add weather api now. I use weatherstack.com. If I use their example this works, but if I adjust it to my own liking I always end up with the same error.

`condition = api_response['current']['weather_descriptions'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

This is the code I am using.

```py
class Actionweatherapi(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "actions.weatherapi"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        import requests
        location = tracker.get_slot('location')
        if location == 'None':
            location = 'fetch:ip'
        api_result = requests.get('http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=0000000&query={}'.format(location))
        api_response = api_result.json()
        country = api_response['request']['query']
        condition = api_response['current']['weather_descriptions']
        temperature_c = api_response['current']['temperature']
        humidity = api_response['current']['humidity']
        wind_mph = api_response['current']['wind_speed']
        response = """It is currently {} in {} at the moment. The temperature is {} degrees, the humidity is {}% and the wind speed is {} mph.""".format(condition, country, temperature_c, humidity, wind_mph)
        dispatcher.utter_message(response)
        return [AllSlotsReset()]
```

I have also reviewed the printf-style String Formatting on the python website, but I cannot figure out how to get it working.

The json response is like this example
http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=1c80e8b9fe4fcef4f8d6fd7514a8e9e9&query=New%20York

Comment: Can you please try to print `api_response` so that we can see how the actual payload looks like? Your code looks fine to me and works with the provided example.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I found the solution on rasa forum. it was just indentation error. The script works.

Comment: perfect! congrats! Please mark your question as resolved then and add the solution.